# Getting initial elapsed time SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skscene

Inside my scene, I have overridden the default `-(void) update: (CFTimeInterval) currentTime` function. It is worth noting that the `currentTime` variable is actually the elapsed time since the beginning of a presumably arbitrary system time, as opposed to the elapsed time since last frame. This update function runs through all of my characters and applies their movement based on velocity per second and elapsed time since last update in seconds. The usual way to get the elapsed time since last update in seconds is to have an NSTimeInterval in your class that stores the last update, and subtract the last update time from the current update time, getting elapsed seconds. However, the initial elapsed time is NOT zero. As such, subtracting zero from a very large number produces a perceived elapsed time of many tens of thousands of seconds. As such, any characters already in motion on the very first frame will have moved very far away.

The obvious solution to this would be to initially set the last update time to the initial time elapsed. However, I do not see any method to access this within `SKScene`, or more specifically within `-(void) didMoveToView: (SKView *) view`.

Another solution would be to set the initial CFTimeInterval to a negative number, such as `-1`. Then, one would check each update function whether the time is `-1`. If so, one would set the elapsed time since last update to `0`, otherwise one would do the ordinary `elapsedTime = currentTime - lastUpdate`. However, doing this if statement every single update function seems messy and unneeded.

Are there any other ways of finding this elapsed time since last update accurately?

Comment: Unless your game is a real-time simulation, does it make sense to use the time interval in that way? If the game skips an update or two, does it make sense to make the characters instantly jump to a new position? Is that fair to the user? Also, what happens to elapsedTime when the user presses the Home button and then restarts the game at a later time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that checking for a flag every iteration is wasteful, so it's a question of what's the *most efficient* solution.

I would think the best (read: most efficient) solution would be to not apply any changes in the first `update` besides simply saving the currentTime variable. This shouldn't affect your gameplay at all; nobody will notice the frame has been dropped. You could do it by saving a pointer to a function, calling that function in the first iteration of `update` which will also change the pointer to another function, and then `update` will call the second function from that point onward.

The method I think you're looking for is `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent`, but SK's `update` method tends to hand back a different, earlier time, likely due to the amount of time taken to pass the time into `update` versus just using `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent`. If you're OK with a little extra overhead without using an `if`, disregard `currentTime` and always use `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent` in your `update` method.

Then again, if you're worried about the overhead of a single `if` statement in each frame, you wouldn't be using a framework. 60 `if`s per second is trivial work for even the slowest mobile processor anyway.

Comment: This really seems like a case of premature optimization.  I'm doubting his game is slowing down because of this issue.  It is the accepted way to check for differences in time.  If it aint broke why fix it??

Comment: @hamobi I'm fixing this, not just for efficiency, but also for cleanliness. It is not very attractive to have an if statement in your main update function that will only be true once.

Comment: its up to you.  i just figure if its good enough for the guys at apple who created the framework, its probably good enough for the rest of us.

Comment: Interesting that my, unique, solution was downvoted, yet the answer that just repeated what the asker already stated was upvoted. And @hamobi that's exactly what I said: "Then again, if you're worried about the overhead of a single if statement in each frame, you wouldn't be using a framework. 60 ifs per second is trivial work for even the slowest mobile processor anyway."

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand.. but I may not.  So correct me if I'm wrong.  But your problem is that your initial delta time is very large, and so using that value to move characters results in them jumping immediately on the first frame of your game.  If thats the case, then youre missing a crucial piece of the code in update.

```
if self.last_update_time == 0.0 {  // this is the important part
    self.delta = 0
} else {
    self.delta = currentTime - self.last_update_time
}

self.last_update_time = currentTime
```

`last_update_time` time will always be 0 when your game starts, and delta will always be 0 too. After that point, your delta value will be very small numbers which you can use to progressively move your sprites.

hopefully this was helpful

Comment: He said that he already considered this approach, he's asking for other possible solutions.